# How does iteration process works

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't understand how the following loop works. I have this binding called JOURNAL,

```
var JOURNAL = [
  {"events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["bread","pudding","brushed teeth","weekend","touched tree"],"squirrel":false},
  {"events":["carrot","nachos","brushed teeth","cycling","weekend"],"squirrel":false}
];
```

The following code loop through it

```
 function tableFor(event, journal) {
   let table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
   for (let i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
     let entry = journal[i], index = 0;
     if (entry.events.includes(event)) index += 1;
     if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
     table[index] += 1;
}
   return table;
 }
console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
```

Which produce

```
     // → [76, 9, 4, 1]
```

My problem is tracing the producing output. I tried taking time to study it for couple of hours now, but no i couldn't understand. I need detailed explanation on how it this loop works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every row:

```
If "pizza" in events => increment table[index = 0 + 1]
else
If "squirrel" == true => increment table[index = 0 + 2]
else
If "pizza" in events AND "squirrel" == true => increment table[index = 0 + 1 + 2]
else
increment table[index = 0]
```

Comment: It seems clear now, but `table[index = 0 + 1]` does this mean index of 0 and 1 OR is an addition?

Comment: @kofoworola-sadique In case `table[index = 0 + 1] += 1` I meant `table[1] += 1`. In case `table[index = 0 + 1 + 2] += 1` I meant `table[3] += 1`.

Comment: Oh. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Each entry in the returned table is the total number of journal entries that match a different combination of conditions.

- 0 = no conditions matched
- 1 = The journal entry's `events` array contains the given `event`.
- 2 = The journale entry's `squirrel` property is true.
- 3 = Both conditions match.

So for each entry it starts by setting `index` to `0`, which is nothing matching. Then it adds `1` and `2` for each of the conditions it wants to test. If both are true, they add up to `3`.

If there were a third condition, it would add `4` for that. Each successive increment should be the next power of `2`. The resulting index is a bit mask with a `1` bit for each matching condition.